# SQL query to find a range of months and days but not year

Tags: sql

one of the column of my table is dates ('ymd'). I need a query that helps me select all records within a certain date range where year doesn't matter (e.g. from 05/12 to 07/12, any year). What's a good way to approach so?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One method converts the date to an mmdd format and then uses that for comparison.  For instance:

```
where extract(month from date) * 100 + extract(day from date) between 0512 and 0712
```

`extract()` is common to both Postgres and MySQL, so this should work in both your originally tagged databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you could simply use the DATE_FORMAT function, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%m%d') BETWEEN 0512 and 0712;
```

If you are using postgres you can use to_char for this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE to_char(datecolumn, 'MMDD')::INTEGER BETWEEN 0512 and 0712;
```